# uso de parámetros de entrada con vistas de cálculo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vistas, sap, hana

encuentre una forma de como filtrar una variable dentro de una vista dentro de hana, el cual ayudara a ser más dinámico las vistas Analíticas.
Espero les sirva.

ALTER PROCEDURE "SP_PruebaVista"()
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
AS
BEGIN
Declare Mes1 DATE ;

```
            SELECT 
            ADD_MONTHS(
            ADD_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE,-EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)),
            1)INTO Mes1 FROM DUMMY;
```

SELECT
"Cliente_ID",
"Domicilio_ID",
"Vendedor_ID",
"Analista_ID",
"Supervisor_ID",
"Gerencia_ID",
"UnidadNegocio_ID",
"Sectorista_ID",
"TipoGerencia_ID",
"Procedencia_ID",
"Periodo_ID",
"Periodo_VendedorID",
"CtaContable",
"DocumentoInterno",
"TipoDocumento",
"DocumentoLegal",
"Asiento",
"FechaCont",
"FechaEmision",
"FechaVencimiento",
"DiasVencimiento",
"TerminoPago_Resumen"
FROM "_SYS_BIC"."Ventas.DM_DEUDA/FACT_DEUDAS_FECHACIERRE"
(placeholder."$$Fecha_Cierre$$"=>:Mes1);

```
        /*(PLACEHOLDER.'$$Fecha_Cierre$$'=>
             -----------------------------
            CURRENT_DATE
            );  */
             -----------------------------
```

END;

CALL "SP_PruebaVista"();

Comment: hola.. por favor podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask]. Cual es la pregunta? tene en cuenta que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, no un blog. Ademas, la mayoria de esas etiquetas que tiene que ver con lo que aca estas preguntando?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.